# Facebook App Invite Links not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I'm trying to setup app invites. Basically I want users to invite their facebook friend to try and install my app. I did setup app links in facebook. This is what I did

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Instead of play store url, i tried putting my app url, but not working. I read the FB documents, it's so confusing, I'm not clear on what is what.

Also, what is the below is for? I belive it's for deep linking. Is that correct? I don't want deep linking for now. Now I only want users to invites their FB friends and when they click on the invite, it should take them to android store

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem before.

Go to your app setting then define your app "namespace". Afterthat, your app invite will works.